React Unity WebGL Not Working | Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState')
I'm currently setting up a basic React website that includes a WebGL application. I successfully followed the 'Getting Started' guide for React [1], and then I tried to integrate a WebGL application using a simple example [2].
But I am receiving a null error message.

Error Message
Directories VSCode
WebGL Application github.io

Code from App.js:
import React from "react";
import { Unity, useUnityContext } from "react-unity-webgl";

function App() {
  const { unityProvider } = useUnityContext({
    loaderUrl: "Webbuild/Build/Webbuild.loader.js",
    dataUrl: "Webbuild/Build/Webbuild.data",
    frameworkUrl: "Webbuild/Build/Webbuild.framework.js",
    codeUrl: "Webbuild/Build/Webbuild.wasm",
  });
  
  return <Unity uunityProvider={unityProvider} />
}

export default App;

Does anyone have a solution for this issue?
Thank you!
[1] https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/ 
[2] https://react-unity-webgl.dev/docs/quick-start/simple-example
I tried looking for different solutions on here, but a lot of them don't follow the same "simple example" i was trying to implement.
I was expecting the webgl application to run similar to this https://sean-sanii-nejad.github.io/PixelGame/

So I recreated how you have setup your environment in vscode and have noticed you have a typo on your component props (needs to be unityProvider instead of uunityProvider).
You might also need to play around with where you webgl files sit within the CRA public folder, I would recommend it has its own dedicated folder within public.
Here is the example code I used to get it to work (Basically the same as the Getting-Started guide)
import React from "react";
import { Unity, useUnityContext } from "react-unity-webgl";

function App() {
 const { unityProvider } = useUnityContext({
   loaderUrl: "build/crateclicker.loader.js",
   dataUrl: "build/crateclicker.data",
   frameworkUrl: "build/crateclicker.framework.js",
   codeUrl: "build/crateclicker.wasm",
 });

return (
  <>
    <Unity
      unityProvider={unityProvider}
      style={{ width: 800, height: 600 }}
    />
  </>
 );
}

export default App;

